# Getting values out of a promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have the following function and I want it to return the variable `recordset`, or more accurately I want to be able to access that info from the code that calls the `getData()` function. How can I do this?

```
function getData() {
    sql.connect("mssql://username:password@localhost/mytestdatabase").then(function () {
        return new sql.Request().query('select * from _table')
            .then(function (recordset) {
                console.log(recordset); // <-- THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO RETURN
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log("Query Error: " + err);
            })
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log("Connection Error: " + err);
    })
};
```

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to use more promises (or rather, return the promise).

Comment: you need to return the connect(), which should give you a promise you can consume downstream.

Comment: Also, your error handling is wrong.  You should leave errors so that the caller can handle them.  Read http://blog.slaks.net/2015-06-10/advanced-promise-usage/

Comment: *"I have the following function and I want it to return the variable `recordset`"* You can't. *"or more accurately I want to be able to access that info from the code that calls the `getData()` function."* Have it return a promise, and have that code consume the promise.

Comment: literally, just prepend `return ` to the function body to be able to `getData().then()` anywhere...

Comment: @dandavis OK, so if I do that and am returning the `sql.connect()`, what would my `.then(` look like to access the `recordset`?

Comment: you can just wrap a one-parameter anon around the code following the call, where the data is needed; the recordset (or something to get at it) should be that first (and only) argument.

Comment: @dandavis could you post an e.g. ? I'm not quite sure how that would work, and I'd like to mark something as the answer.

Comment: `var x=a(); b(x);` becomes `a().then(b)`, this question is dead now...